# Rotate Rows to Columns MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rows, reshape

I've been researching this and have not found a solution.  I have data that is like this: `x = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;]` and I need it to look like this to create an index: `xx = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]`.  So, `x` is a `3 X 3` and I need `xx` to be a `1 X 9`.  The `reshape` in its' basic form, does not accomplish this but maybe there is a variation of the `reshape` function that will work?

Comment: Have you looked at [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)? You could use it together with `reshape` to get your desired result.

Comment: Do `transpose` and then move around the neck a bit, it might popup, I mean the solution might popup.

Comment: Also for your example `y = y'; xx = y(:);` gives your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
>> x = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;]
x =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
>> reshape(x',1,9)
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: perfect - thanks!  I should have seen that solution!

Comment: @user2100039 Could you upvote your accepted answer as well as accepting it to maximise the answerer's efforts, please.

Answer (score 1):

This does not give you as much flexibility as [reshape](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) but I does the job.

```
x = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;]
x.'(:).'
ans =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

Comment: FYI, the second statement can be chained like that **only** if you're Octave.  You have to explicitly split the second line of code into three statements if you're using MATLAB: `x = x.'; x = x(:); x = x.';`... yuck.

Comment: @rayryeng Many thanks... :-) And thanks for pointing the Octave bit out. I didn't think of that.

Comment: Ahhh FWIW I like chaining things like that together. I wish you could do that in MATLAB! You're welcome btw. :)